# strange behaviour that filters have when dealing with each request

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

below is some simple code:

```
[SimpleFilter]
public class MyController : ControllerBase
{
   public MyController() {
      <---------- I put a debugger here
   }

   [Route("")]
   public string Get() {
      return DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
   }
}

public class SimpleFilterAttribute : Attribute, IAsyncResourceFilter
{
   
   public SimpleFilterAttribute() {
      // <---------- I put a debugger here
   }

   public async Task OnResourceExecutionAsync(ResourceExecutingContext context, ResourceExecutionDelegate next) {
     ...
   }
}
```

So we know that when the appication is running, it will create a new controller instance to handle each request, so if I make 5 requests, then 5 `MyController` instance will be newed up, I can verify it by putting a debugger in MyController's constructor, every time the control goes to the debugger.

So I assume the same thing should happen to filter too, a new fiter instance will be created to handle every new request, but strange things happen as below:

1-When the application first starts, the SimpleFilter's constructor gets invoke twice, which means two instance of `SimpleFilter` newed up, so why application creates two instances of this fiter?

2-After the application is running, everytime I make a new request, no new SimpleFilter instance created, it looks like a single filter instance is used to handle all requests, is it true? If it is true, why we need a new controller instance for every request while only a single filter instance is needed for all requests?

Comment: Controllers have lifetime dependencies, like DbContext, so state management is absolutely required. Attributes have static data, known during compilation, so you can use the same instance.

Comment: @FireAlkazar thanks for your answer. But why the filter get created twice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting question about two times called filter constructor.

It looks it is CLR specific behaviour not `aspnet-core`. Each time `TypeInfo.GetCustomAttributes()` is called, attribute instance is created.

You can check that yourself by calling

```
var typeInfo = typeof(MyController).GetTypeInfo();
var attribes = typeInfo.GetCustomAttributes();
```

And while constructing controller info `TypeInfo.GetCustomAttributes()` is called at least 2 times
https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/ApplicationModels/DefaultApplicationModelProvider.cs#L110